# Trim text in a table column header with sort indicator

Tags: c++, qt, qheaderview

I have a table with styled column headers.
Header height is limited so the headers are actually narrow.
The header has also the sort indicator (the default arrow/triangle).

When the user changes the width of a column such that it is smaller than the text's width, the text is trimmed with 3 dots at the end. E.g. "Universi..." 
So far so good.

The thing is the sort indicator hides part of the trimmed text.
Imagine wide column - the text is fully show and the sort icon is on the right and everthing looks good. Now the user resizes the column. Just before the text is trimmed with 3 dots, the sort indicator starts to hide the right side of the text. At some point the text is trimmed with the sort indicator on top of the 3 dots . E.g. "Universi.▽" or even "Univers▽".

It looks like the header does not take into account the sort sign.
Is there a simple way to set the sign indicator to not overlap the trimmed text e.g. "Univer... ▽"?
I need the columns to be resizable and sortable.

I don't want to define a special widget with push button and text box and handle events and trimming and so... it is a serious overhead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-629
Which should be solved in Qt 5.4 https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/99900/